# Невозможно поместить клаузу WITH FUNCTION в BEGIN/END блок

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Почему не компилируется следующий код?

```
DECLARE c number;
BEGIN
    WITH FUNCTION calculate(i IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
        r number;
    BEGIN
        r := i*i;
        RETURN r;
    END;
    select calculate(1) INTO c from dual;
END;
/
```

Ошибка компиляции:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 19:
PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06550: line 3, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Хотя сам запрос выполняется:

```
WITH FUNCTION calculate(i IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
    r number;
BEGIN
    r := i*i;
    RETURN r;
END;
select calculate(1) from dual
/

CALCULATE(1)
------------
           1
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Unable to put a WITH FUNCTION clause in a BEGIN/END block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41549798) от участника [@user2672165](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2672165/user2672165)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, что эта конструкция еще не поддерживается в PL/SQL. Предположительно, она будет добавлена в одном из будущих релизов.

А  пока, хотя не совсем красиво, но можно использовать динамический SQL, который выполнит рабочий запрос в SQL контексте, где он поддерживается:

```
declare c number;
begin
    execute immediate '
    WITH FUNCTION calculate(i IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
        r number;
    BEGIN
        r := i*i;
        RETURN r;
    END;
    select calculate(1) from dual' into c;
    dbms_output.put_line ('result '||c);
end;
/

result 1
```

В документации [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html#GUID-6E14E04D-4344-45F3-BE80-979DD26C7A90) клауза `WITH` вообще не упомянута, хотя она уже работала для статических запросах в боле старых релизах. В [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) нет упоминания об ограничении использовния в PL/SQL контексте.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41552291) от участника [@Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)</sub>